# Add borders on an MDI child borderless form

Tags: vb.net

I am using this way below, to add **borders** to all my **MDI child** borderless forms...

```
Private Sub Form_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
        Me.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(76, 76, 76)
    Else
        Dim MF_Rect As New Rectangle(5, 5, Me.ClientSize.Width, Me.ClientSize.Height)
        Dim MF_Color = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(76, 76, 76))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(MF_Color, MF_Rect)
        Me.Padding = New Padding(5, 5, 5, 5)
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
    End If
End Sub
```

But, if **MDI child form** steps **out** of **MDI parent's** borders, even half of it, and then **maximize** and **normalize** again, borders are gone!!! If I **slide** it in, I see them again!!!

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: MDI child windows require a standard border, lots of things go wrong when they don't.  You might avoid this particular problem by putting Me.ResizeRedraw = True in the constructor and/or overriding the OnPaintBackground() method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dragging of the form outside of the MDI parent's borders is actually not required to reproduce the behavior. All you need to do is maximize and then normalize the form.

The problem is that the form is not being repainted after it has been resized. This is the default behavior, and it makes some degree of sense—the portion of the client area that is visible has *always* been visible, and therefore is still (presumably) painted correctly. As an optimization, then, no repaint is performed.

But this behavior doesn't work for you, because your painting logic is tied to the current size of the form. If the form changes its size, you want to repaint so that you can calculate new painting dimensions.

You can hack it by forcing an invalidation (and therefore a repaint) of the client area in response to a resize event. The `Invalidate` member function will do this.

But there is a better solution that causes this to happen automatically. Set the form's [`ResizeRedraw` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resizeredraw.aspx) to `true`. You can do this either from the designer (in the Properties window) or in the form class constructor. (Note that this is completely equivalent to calling the `SetStyle` member function and specifying the `ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw` flag.)

An even better approach would be to separate your painting of the borders (which logically are in the non-client area) from your painting of the *contents* of the form (which is the logical client area). I won't go into how to do that in this answer, but you can find a discussion and various tutorials elsewhere online. For example, [Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms](https://customerborderform.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Painting%20NonClient%20Area&referringTitle=Home). This article is actually part of a larger [library](https://customerborderform.codeplex.com/) that implements this effect for you. Not sure how/if that library will work with MDI children. The MDI effect has been deprecated for *many* years…